# class inheritiance, changing a class type in ruby from a parent to a child

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming

I have a regular hash

```
myhash = { :abc => 123 }
```

and a class

```
class SpecialHash < Hash

  def initialize arg_hash
     # how do I say
     self = arg_hash
  end

end
```

or

Is there some way of doing:
   myhash.class = SpecialHash?

-daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution depends on the library you want to extend and on what you are trying to achive.

In case of a Hash, it's quite hard to extend it in that way because there is no initializer you can override when you use the Ruby hash syntax.

However, because creating a new hash with some value is the same of merging an empty hash with the given values, you can do

```
class SpecialHash < Hash
  def initialize(hash)
     self.merge!(hash)
  end
end

myhash = SpecialHash.new(:abc => 123)
```

`myhash` will then be an instance of `SpecialHash` with the same properties of a Hash.

Notice the use of `merge!` that is actually changing the value of `self`. Using `self.merge` will not have the same effect.

Comment: It isn't that `merge!` is changing the value of `self` (like `self = something_else` would if it were possible), but that `merge!` is mutating the Hash that is referred to by `self`. So, for example, `self.object_id` will remain unchanged.

Comment: Yes, that was the meaning. You can't assign `self` in Ruby, but in this way you work around this because you merge the content of the new argument inside the Hash referenced by `self`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you knew, but I wanted to clarify for anyone reading since that's an area that confuses a lot of people.